# ASSERT failure in QList<T>::at: "index out of range" in Qt 5

Tags: qt5

I want to generate *.png files from my directory randomly in qt using qrand() function.
to do that I have created a QStringList object so that I can store all files I have in my 
directory.thinking that I have some list of files in my QStringList object when I run my application it crush.

I have also warning in my issue pane:> **warning: unknown escape sequence: '\D' [enabled by default]**

```
applicationPath = "C:\\Users\\Tekme\Documents\\QtProject\\4Toddler";
                   ^
```

the reason I add the above warning issues is that, I am on window machine so I am thinking the problem can be **path** problem

the code is

```
QString MainWindow::randomIcon()
{
        QStringList iconFileList;
        QString searchPath = applicationPath + "\\icons";//applicationPath = 

        QDir directory = QDir(searchPath);
        QStringList filters;
        filters << "*.png";
        directory.setNameFilters(filters);
        iconFileList = directory.entryList(QDir::AllEntries);//i have 6 *.png files


        int randomIndex = qrand() % iconFileList.count();

        return iconFileList.at(randomIndex);//my application crash here
}
```

Even when I try to replace iconFileList.at(randomIndex) by iconFileList.at(2) it crush.
I am sure I have more than 2 files in my directory

Comment: its always worth checking for `directory.exists()` and `!iconFileList.isEmpty()`

Comment: I feel silly for making such kind of error. thank for your tip, finally i used !conFileList.isEmpty() i helped me a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the error:

```
applicationPath = "C:\\Users\\Tekme\Documents\\QtProject\\4Toddler";
```

Should be

```
applicationPath = "C:\\Users\\Tekme\\Documents\\QtProject\\4Toddler";
```

You are missing an extra slash